# Express js multiple operations gm (GraphicsMagick) module

Tags: node.js, express, graphicsmagick

Using Expressjs with gm (GraphicsMagick) module.

Currently (see code)operation #1 and #2 work correctly when executed separately, but they do not work together (as seen below).

I would like to combine both operations in one statement, any suggestions?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var gm = require('gm'); // GraphicsMagick

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    gm('image.png') 
        // Operation #1
        .composite('topimage.png')
        .geometry('+200+200')

        // Operation #2
        .drawText(5, 20, 'my text')
        .fontSize(20)
        .font(__dirname + 'fonts/MyFont.TTF')

        .stream(function streamOut (err, stdout, stderr) {
            stdout.pipe(res); //pipe to response
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while of struggle I found that gm() can take a Stream as the input param. The following code solves my question.

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router(); 
var gm = require('gm'); // GraphicsMagick

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

   gm(gm('image.png') 
                 // Operation #1
            .composite('topimage.png')
            .geometry('+200+200')
            .stream())

                 // Operation #2
            .drawText(5, 20, 'my text')
            .fontSize(20)
            .font(__dirname + 'fonts/MyFont.TTF')

            .stream(function streamOut (err, stdout, stderr) {
                stdout.pipe(res); //pipe to response
            });

    });
```